# Why the setTimeOut still firing even the condition is not met?

Tags: javascript, react-native, settimeout

The `setTimeout` still works even though it didn't go `else`, I confirmed it by displaying `console.log(...)` inside the timer and `else`.

I am expecting the `if` only that will work if the condition is being met and it is. I tried placing the `clearTimeout` as suggest from other post but the problem was not solved.

Can anyone help me how to prevent the `setTimeout` works without deleting it from the condition?

```
useEffect(() => {
   AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
     .then(token => {
       var timer;
       console.log('AsyncStorage (token): ', token);
       console.log('Is token not null? ', token !== null);
       if (token) {
         clearTimeout(timer);
         dispatch(getUserInfoByToken(token));
       } else {
         dispatch(data_not_initialized());
         timer = setTimeout(() => {
           dispatch(tokenIsNull());
         }, 3000);
       }
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
     });
 }, [loginTriggers, goodByeLoading]);
```

EDIT:

I removed the `clearTimeout`, placed it here to show what I have tried.

EDIT 2:

It's okay now. Thanks you all!

Comment: Your `clearTimeout(timer)` doesn't do anything because `timer` is always `undefined` there. But I don't really understand your problem.

Comment: The token is not undefined or null, so `dispatch(getUserInfoByToken(token))` should only work but for some reason even though the `setTimeout` which  isn't inside the `if`, it still fire. I removed the `clearTimeout` from my local.

Comment: `token` has to be falsy at one point. What does the logging output?

Comment: Oh, I think it might be the token but when I check the value of `token`, it is not `undefined` or `null`. But thank you, I'll try different logic.

Comment: It can also be 0, false, NaN or the empty string.

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks to you! The `async` would take time and not sure when it will retrieve, so I guess `AsyncStorage` get the `token` before it being initialized.